# How to find values of a matrix to make it consistent

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

So I have this system of equations

$2x+ky+2z=0$

$x-y+z=1$

$y-z=k$

I augment it as to get:

$\begin{pmatrix}2 & k & 2 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & k 
\end{pmatrix}$

If i reduced the latter in reduced echelon form I get:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 &k+1\\
0 &1 &-1& k\\ 
0 &0 &-k-2 & k²+2(k+1)
\end{pmatrix}$

I need to find the k values for which the system is consistent. It seems to me that the system is consistent when $k\neq -2$.

However, when I plug this matrix in the ti nspire cx cas calculator, I get that the reduced echelon form is

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &k/2 &1& 0\\ 
0 &1 & -1 &k\\ 
0 &0& 1 &-(k²+2k+2)/(k+2)
\end{pmatrix}$

The system for me is still consistent when $k$ is not equal to $-2$, because if it were equal to $-2$ then $z= a$  divided by 0, which makes it undefined.

However, when I try to compute the solutions, meaning $x$, $y$ and $z$, I get different solutions for the matrices. How come? Which one do you think is correct?

E.g with MY REF I get that $x= k+1$. With REF on the calculator I get that 
$x=-y(k/2)-z$.

Can somebody please explain the differences with the ccalculator's REF and my REF , or if maybe the soltuions are the same and i just need to expan better? Thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am new here! Not sure how to use it, some help would be nice, maybe edit the question...

Comment: Instead of reposting [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821435/265466) you should edit the original with whatever updates and clarifications you have.

Comment: @SaraColetti Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

From the augmented matrix we obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & k & 2 & 0\\
1 &-1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1 &-1 &k \\
\end{bmatrix} \to 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & k & 2 & 0\\
0&-2-k&0 &2 \\
0 &1 &-1 &k \\
\end{bmatrix}
\to 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & k & 2 & 0\\
0&-2-k&0 &2 \\
0 &0&-2-k &k(k+2)+2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and thus the system is consistent and has an unique solution for $k\neq -2$ otherwise for $k=-2$ for the second and third equation we obtain $0=2$.

Note also that for $k=-2$ the first 2 equations ofbthe original system become

- $2x-2y+2x=0 \implies x-y+z=0$
- $x-y+z=1$

which are clearly  not consistent.

Comment: Yes. I knew that... However my doubt was why , when solving for x,y,z , i got different equations.

Comment: Check your calculation maybe you did some mistake.

Comment: Can you please tell me , from the REF i showed above, the one done by hand and not in the calculator

Comment: If x=k+1 and y= -2/ (k+2)? I just want to check if my answers are correct

Comment: From thr REEF system you can immediately obtain the solution. For y=-2/(k+2) it is correct, to find x we need z from the third equation.

Comment: Notably we have $z=-k-2/(k+2)$ and then $2x-4/(k+2)-2k-4/(k+2)=0$ that is $x=k+4/(k+2)$.

Comment: Am i correct by saying that the system for me is still consistent when k is not equal to −2, because if it were equal to −2 then z=a divided by 0, which makes it undefined. (In relation the the REF of the calculator)

Comment: Yes you can also conclude in that way solving for k and then observing that for k=-2 the system has not solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to find all x, y , z in terms of k 
Proceed to plug them in the equation generated by your calculator and check if they match.
Hopefully it provides a relationship between all variables by default...

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & k & 2 & 0\\
1 &-1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1 &-1 &k \\
\end{bmatrix} \to 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac k2 & 1 & 0\\
1 &-1 &1 &1 \\
0 &1 &-1 &k \\
\end{bmatrix} \to 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac k2 & 1 & 0\\
0 &-\frac k2-1 &0 &1 \\
0 &1 &-1 &k \\
\end{bmatrix} \to \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac k2 & 1 & 0\\
0 &1 &0 &-\frac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &1 &-1 &k \\
\end{bmatrix} \to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & \frac{2}{k+2}\\
0 &1 &0 &-\frac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &0 &-1 &k+\frac{2}{k+2} \\
\end{bmatrix} \to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & k+1\\
0 &1 &0 &-\frac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &0 &1 &-k-\frac{2}{k+2} \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Hence, it is consistent only when $k\ne-2$.

Also, if you plug in $y$ and $z$:
$$x=-y(k/2)-z=-\left(-\frac{2}{k+2}\right)\cdot \frac k2-\left(-k-\frac{2}{k+2}\right)=k+1.$$