# How to find solutions of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I need to find the solutions of a matrix.

So I have this system of equations

$2x+ky+2z=0$

$x-y+z=1$

$y-z=k$

I augment it as to get:

$\begin{pmatrix}2 & k & 2 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & k 
\end{pmatrix}$

If i reduced the latter in reduced echelon form I get:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 &k+1\\
0 &1 &-1& k\\ 
0 &0 &-k-2 & k²+2(k+1)
\end{pmatrix}$

I was thinking that the solutions for x,y,z are

x=k+1

y= -2/k+2

z= -(k²+2k+2) / k+2

Are my solutions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking that the solutions for x,y,z are
>
> x=k+1
>
> y= -2/k+2
>
> z= -(k²+2k+2) / k+2
>
> Are my solutions correct?

Apart from sloppy notation (don't forget brackets!), this is correct. At least for $k \ne -2$; what happens for $k=-2$? You can substitute into the reduced echelon form to check. So you get:

- For $k \ne -2$:
  $$x = k+1 \quad,\quad y = -\frac{2}{k+2}\quad,\quad z = -\frac{k^2+2k+2}{k+2}$$
- For $k = -2$:
  $$\ldots$$